# How to rewrite the url to deal with uniqueness of slug name in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Currently my URL look something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/cat/subcat1-cat/subcat2-cat
```

How can I make it look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/cat/subcat1/subcat2
```

Basically I want to remove the `-cat` in this case. I can't find any workaround for this annoying problem in Wordpress so I think `.htaccess` will be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try edit categories in wordpress dashboard and change alias for each categories.